# camel mock - MockEndpoint.whenAnyExchangeReceived process method not execute

Tags: apache-camel

I have example code below, why is the process method in MockEndpoint.whenAnyExchangeReceived NOT executed?

I expect the response is "Expected Body from mock remote http call", but the actual response is what passed in request("Camel rocks").

```
public class CamelMockRemoteHttpCallTest extends CamelTestSupport {

    @Override
    protected RouteBuilder createRouteBuilder() throws Exception {
        return new RouteBuilder() {
            @Override
            public void configure() throws Exception {
                from("direct:start")
                    .to("http://abc/bcd")
                    ;
            }
        };
    }

    @Override
    public String isMockEndpointsAndSkip() {
        return "http://abc/bcd";
    }

    @Test
    public void testSimulateErrorUsingMock() throws Exception {
        MockEndpoint http = getMockEndpoint("mock:http://abc/bcd");

        http.whenAnyExchangeReceived(new Processor() {
            public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
                exchange.getOut().setBody("Expected Body from mock remote http call");   //why this line doesn't execute
            }
        });

        String response = template.requestBody("direct:start", "Camel rocks", String.class);

        assertEquals("Expected Body from mock remote http call", response);  //failed, the actual response is "Camel rocks"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have added some breakpoints to your test and it seems, that automatically created mock endpoint is `mock://http:abc/bcd`, not `mock:http://abc/bcd`.

To find, why is this happening, you can look to method `org.apache.camel.impl.InterceptSendToMockEndpointStrategy#registerEndpoint`, which is called as part of mock endpoint auto registration. There is `//` removed from http URI. And then to `org.apache.camel.util.URISupport#normalizeUri` method, where is `//` added for `mock` uri prefix.

There is also nice comment in implementation of `InterceptSendToMockEndpointStrategy`, but I couldn't find it mentioned in documentation.

> // create mock endpoint which we will use as interceptor 
>   // replace :// from scheme to make it easy to lookup the mock endpoint without having double :// in uri

When you change it to `getMockEndpoint("mock://http:abc/bcd")`, the test passes.

The best way to avoid these issues, is pass `false` as second parameter of `getMockEndpoint()` method, if you expect already created endpoint. This will throw exception, if mock endpoint does not exists. Otherwise is new mock endpoint created on demand.

Comment: Thank you Bedla!  It works after I updated to exactly what you said.

Comment: @ChinLiang, if the answer helped you please consider accepting it as the correct answer and upvoting it.