# Apache Camel http mock testing fails with Connection refused

Tags: apache-camel

I am testing this Camel route:

```
  from("direct:start")
    .setHeader(Exchange.HTTP_METHOD, constant("GET"))
    .to("http://127.0.0.1:8088/")
    .to("mock:result");
```

...using this mock server:

```
mockServer = MockRestServiceServer.createServer(new RestTemplate());

mockServer.expect(
    requestTo("http://127.0.0.1:8088/"))
    .andExpect(method(HttpMethod.GET))
    .andRespond(withStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
        .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
        .body("")
     );
```

...but receive:

```
I/O exception (java.net.ConnectException) caught when processing request: Connection refused: connect
```

Are there anything obvious I am missing? How can I proceed to find the cause?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use `MockRestServiceServer`. This does not start real server and therefore can be used only for mocking responses to Spring RestTemplate. Apache Camel does not utilize RestTemplate for sending requests, it uses Apache HttpClient.

You can either:

- Advice your http endpoint with mock endpoint - preferred way. Example using `isMockEndpointsAndSkip` eg here: [camel mock - MockEndpoint.whenAnyExchangeReceived process method not execute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50201617/camel-mock-mockendpoint-whenanyexchangereceived-process-method-not-execute)
- Or start any full Http server in your unit test - For this you can extend `HttpServerTestSupport` containing some prepared methods - example [HttpBodyTest](https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/master/components/camel-http4/src/test/java/org/apache/camel/component/http4/HttpBodyTest.java)